# Bash script not working with crontab

Tags: bash, shell, cron, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I own a raspberry pi that runs raspbian jessie. I'm using this raspberry with motioneye as a system surveillance. Motioneye records files to a sd card but i want to delete older files in folder /var/lib/motioneye when disk usage is coming full. Motioneye records movie files in /var/lib/motioneye with subdirectories for each day like /var/lib/motioneye/2016-02-13/files_in_order. Motioneye records files with this permission drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Feb 13 17:03 2016-02-13 so i can't delete files with user access, i need to be in root. I can run the script with no problems with

```
sudo bash ./deleteoldfiles.sh
```

but when i enter it in crontab the script is not working, i tried entering paths with no success. I found this script on internet, modified a little so it can accept folders instead of mounting drivers and i wrote in script folder link and max usage. My script looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/home/pi/
############################################################################### 
# Author            :  Louwrentius
# Contact           : louwrentius@gmail.com
# Initial release   : August 2011
# Licence           : Simplified BSD License
############################################################################### 

VERSION=1.01

#
# Mounted volume to be monitored.
#
MOUNT="/var/lib/motioneye"
#
# Maximum threshold of volume used as an integer that represents a percentage:
# 95 = 95%.
#
MAX_USAGE="90"
#
# Failsafe mechansim. Delete a maxium of MAX_CYCLES files, raise an error after
# that. Prevents possible runaway script. Disable by choosing a high value.
#
MAX_CYCLES=10


show_header () {

echo
echo DELETE OLD FILES $VERSION
echo

}

show_header

reset () {
CYCLES=0
OLDEST_FILE=""
OLDEST_DATE=0
ARCH=`uname`
}

reset

if [ -z "$MOUNT" ] || [ ! -e "$MOUNT" ] || [ ! -d "$MOUNT" ] || [ -z "$MAX_USAGE" ]
then
echo "Usage: $0 <mountpoint> <threshold>"
echo "Where threshold is a percentage."
echo
echo "Example: $0 /storage 90"
echo "If disk usage of /storage exceeds 90% the oldest"
echo "file(s) will be deleted until usage is below 90%."
echo 
echo "Wrong command line arguments or another error:"
echo 
echo "- Directory not provided as argument or"
echo "- Directory does not exist or"
echo "- Argument is not a directory or"
echo "- no/wrong percentage supplied as argument."
echo
exit 1
fi

check_capacity () {

USAGE=`df -h "$MOUNT"| tail -1 | awk '{ print $5 }' | sed s/%//g`
if [ ! "$?" == "0" ]    
then
echo "Error: mountpoint $MOUNT not found in df output."
exit 1
fi

if [ -z "$USAGE" ]
then
echo "Didn't get usage information of $MOUNT"
echo "Mountpoint does not exist or please remove trailing slash."
exit 1
fi

if [ "$USAGE" -gt "$MAX_USAGE" ]
then
echo "Usage of $USAGE% exceeded limit of $MAX_USAGE percent."
return 0
else
echo "Usage of $USAGE% is within limit of $MAX_USAGE percent."
return 1
fi
}

check_age () {

FILE="$1"
if [ "$ARCH" == "Linux" ]
then
FILE_DATE=`stat -c %Z "$FILE"`
elif [ "$ARCH" == "Darwin" ]
then
FILE_DATE=`stat -f %Sm -t %s "$FILE"`
else
echo "Error: unsupported architecture."
echo "Send a patch for the correct stat arguments for your architecture."
fi

NOW=`date +%s`
AGE=$((NOW-FILE_DATE))
if [ "$AGE" -gt "$OLDEST_DATE" ]
then
export OLDEST_DATE="$AGE"
export OLDEST_FILE="$FILE"
fi
}

process_file () {

FILE="$1"

#
# Replace the following commands with wathever you want to do with 
# this file. You can delete files but also move files or do something else.
#
echo "Deleting oldest file $FILE"
rm -f "$FILE"
}

while check_capacity
do
if [ "$CYCLES" -gt "$MAX_CYCLES" ]
then
echo "Error: after $MAX_CYCLES deleted files still not enough free space."
exit 1
fi


FILES=`find "$MOUNT" -type f`

IFS=$'\n'
for x in $FILES
do
check_age "$x"
done

if [ -e "$OLDEST_FILE" ]
then
#
# Do something with file.
#
process_file "$OLDEST_FILE"
else
echo "Error: somehow, item $OLDEST_FILE disappeared."
fi
((CYCLES++))
done
echo
```

I entered in sudo crontab -e this:

```
#Borrowed from anacron SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
#End borrowed from anacron
* * * * * /home/pi/deleteoldfiles.sh
```

Sorry for long post, I tried to explain what`s happening maybe i get some help. Thank you !

Comment: Do you get any error message? Try to run as `bash -x /home/pi/deleteoldfiles.sh &>/tmp/output` to see what is going on.

Comment: i modified the sudo crontab -e with 
      `#Borrowed from anacron`
    `SHELL=/bin/sh`
    `PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin`
    `#End borrowed from anacron`
    `# */5 * * * * /home/pi/deleteoldfiles.sh`
    `* * * * *   bash -x /home/pi/deleteoldfiles.sh &>/tmp/output`
but in tmp/output all i can see is a blank file.

Comment: In this case you can probably simplify your question a lot. Try to replace your long script with a simple one only doing something like `date >/tmp/time`. This should work manually but not in cron.

Comment: add the line 'MAILTO=someone@somewhere' to the crontab file to get the output of all executed commands. This will give you a hint about whats happening.

Comment: Is the script's execute bit set? i.e. can you run it manually as `./deleteoldfiles.sh` rather than `bash ./deleteoldfiles.sh`?

Answer (score 0):

I did it !
i erased all in sudo crontab -e and entered in crontab -e only this line

`* * * * *   sudo bash -x /home/pi/deleteoldfiles.sh > /home/pi/output.txt 2>&1`

and it's working, i have a log file which i can track if it`s working good.
Thank you all !

Comment: And why is that working?

Answer (score 0):

Fine script, but you should add these two lines after `((CYCLES++))`:

```
OLDEST_FILE=""
OLDEST_DATE=0
```

to delete the new oldest file.